# How to merge multiple columns having same column name in one dataframe with rules python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with multiple columns having the same name. I want to merge the values and keep only the unique columns as outputs with certain rules to choose between two conflicting values. And if the values are the same, just select one. This is how my CSV would look like. (P.S. My CSV doesn't have headings separated with an underscore. For sake of creating dataframe, I have used underscore.)

```
df_data_hworkforce = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ['Afghanistan','Bahrain','Djibouti','Egypt','Iran'], 
           "2019": [2.9,28,2.1,8.5,15.2],
            "2019_1": [np.nan,27.9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan ],
            "2018": [2.9,27.3,1.1,6.5,5.2],
            "2018_1": [2.9,27,2.1,6,np.nan],
            "2017": [3,26,1.9,np.nan,np.nan],
            })
```

Directly creating same name dataframe was not possible. So doing this to present an example.

```
df_data_hworkforce.rename(columns = {'2019_1':'2019','2018_1':'2018'},inplace = True)
```

This is how dataframe looks like
[image]

Joining the columns with same name the following way:

```
def sjoin(x): return ';'.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))
df_data_hworkforce.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.apply(sjoin, axis=1))
```

This combines the value of two columns and gives the following results.

[image]

However, my desired output is to select only one data when the data is same in both columns and if they are different by less than 0.5, select the not rounded off value. Below is my desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very peculiar data transformation and can not be implemented very efficiently.

However an approach you can take is:

1. `groupby` each pairing of data values
2. `agg`regate according to your desired threshold & transformation
3. Update original data

```py
def combine(df, threshold=.5):
    arr = df.astype(float).to_numpy().T
    diffs = np.nan_to_num(arr - arr[:, None, :], 0)
    max_diffs = abs(diffs).max(axis=(0, 1))
    
    non_rounded_values = ((arr.round() != arr) & ~np.isnan(arr)).argmax(axis=0)
    rounded_values = ((arr.round() == arr) & ~np.isnan(arr)).argmax(axis=0)
    non_rounded_values[non_rounded_values == 0] += rounded_values[non_rounded_values == 0]
    
    cat_values = (
        df.astype(str)
        .where(df.notnull())
        .apply(lambda row: ';'.join(row.dropna().drop_duplicates()), axis=1)
    )
    
    choices = np.where(max_diffs >= threshold, non_rounded_values, len(df.columns))
    return choices.choose([*arr, cat_values])

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=zip(*[
        ['Afghanistan','Bahrain','Djibouti','Egypt','Iran'],
        [2.9,28,2.1,8.5,15.2],
        [2.0,28,2.0,8.5,15.2],
        [np.nan,27.9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan ],
        [2.9,27.3,1.1,6.5,5.2],
        [2.9,27,2.1,6,np.nan],
        [3,26,1.9,np.nan,np.nan],
    ]),
    columns=['Country', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2018', '2018', '2017']
)

to_update = (
    df.select_dtypes('number')
    .loc[:, lambda d: d.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]
    .groupby(level=0, axis=1).agg(combine, threshold=.5)
)

out = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()].copy()
out.update(to_update)

print(out.fillna('').sort_index(axis=1))
       Country     2019     2018  2017
0  Afghanistan  2.9;2.0      2.9   3.0
1      Bahrain     27.9     27.3  26.0
2     Djibouti      2.1  1.1;2.1   1.9
3        Egypt      8.5  6.5;6.0   NaN
4         Iran     15.2      5.2   NaN
```

---

Update: simplified the code since the column names are exact matches.

Comment: Actually my dataset doesn't have an underscore as I am importing my CSV. Here I used underscore as I could not upload CSV here and show it. If I had not used underscore here, while creating data frame, pandas would ignore the same column names and would use only the later column. I did not know the other way of creating data frame with the same name columns. Could you please update the answer removing the underscore clause?

Comment: Updated my answer. This actually simplifies the code since we don't need to apply any transformation/splitting step. We can simply perform a groupby operation along the columns.

Comment: Got an error called "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' "

Comment: something to do with the zip I believe as I have not done that in datasets.  So, I tried this: imported_all_data = zip(*imported_all_data). For the line to_update = (
    imported_all_data.loc[:, imported_all_data.columns.duplicated(keep=False)] this line I got "AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'loc'"

Comment: Updated again to handle N columns as well as filtering out non-numeric data. If you don't want to filter, you'll need to apply your own casting logic to ensure your values are prepped.